# Add <p> tags to plain text paragraph

Tags: jquery, html, text, formatting

I am trying to write a script to automate a rather long and painful process I am required to do at work.

**Scenario:**
In short, I am given a text document that has 4 lines of text and two line breaks, and this format repeats for 5 to 8 pages. I then have to extract 6 pieces of information from each "paragraph" and type them out into a table in another document.

Since the output I get is formatted (including the fields that I extract data from), I would like to be able to paste my text into a textbox, click convert, and have it return the results I need and list them in a table.

**Where I need help/advise:**
From my limited JavaScript knowledge, I am thinking that I need to set `<p>` tags around each 4-line "paragraph." Then I should be able to write a script that would select the `<p>` tag, extract the data I need, write it to the table, and repeat the process for the next `<p>` tag.

I know there are online options that will do this for me (textfixer.com, for example), but my system is not connected to the internet, and for security reasons, it will never be. This means I can not use PHP (which I know better) or any other server-side processing. I am hoping this can be done through JavaScript, so I can process it through a browser. This is a Windows machine so if there is another way to do it, I am open to ideas.

Comment: You're going to have to show some code that demonstrates an effort on your part.  This is not a _"give me the codez"_ site.

Comment: I really don't believe Ryan crosser was asking for "the codez" nor do I believe that all questions must have a code snippet. He is looking for help with the concepts. He's laid out what he has tried so far in the form of his thoughts and then he is quite reasonably asking "where should I go from here". I do not think this is what Jeff Atwood was referring to with that post.

Comment: More relevant to the question: Why javascript? Why not use a language like Perl or Python? Both of those were better at text processing.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Thank you for understanding my question. The first step of this process for me is to add the p tags to the paragraphs in the text. I didn't include the code to extract the data from the text because I didn't see how that is beneficial, but I'll add it. This will run on Windows XP, which is only connected to an intranet. I don't have admin right so I cannot install on the system. I do not know Perl or Python, but I thought they required a server? After looking through the system, I pretty much only have FirFox 3.6.3 to work with, and that is why I am leaning towards JavaScript.

Comment: @Ryan crosser Perl and Python don't require servers, although they do potentially require installation. In theory you should be able to "install" Perl (and probably Python?) in a local directory, if you're okay running the script under your user name. If you're running on Windows XP, don't forget about the shells available there (DOS shell, PowerShell?). Some of those might be able to do in-place stream editing. I'm just not convinced JavaScript is the best solution because its strength is working with a DOM, and your goal is to add HTML to a non-HTML file.

Comment: I will have to see if that would work. This system is locked down pretty tight, users cannot even use flash drives or insert CDs, and I'm not sure that I could convince an admin to do it for me. This limits me to re-typing the code onto the computer directly. I really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the document on a series of three line breaks (one to account for the end of line break, two for the empty lines), and then rejoin them with paragraph tags:

```
// pull the document out
var doc = $("#my-document").val();

// split on double line breaks
// note that we actually split on triple to account for the trailing
// line break at the end of a paragraph
var parts = doc.split("\n\n\n");

// rejoin with paragraph tags
doc = parts.join("</p><p>");

// wrap the entire thing in open/close paragraphs
doc = "<p>" + doc + "</p>";

// and stick it in the output
$("#output").html(doc);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2uMaK/

Comment: This is actually what I thought of last night, but haven't had a chance to test it out. I'll post the results after I test. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in accepting the answer. I ended up using something very similar to this. Thanks.

Comment: No apology necessary. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

yeah,your approach is good. #paragraph will select the code

```
  #paragraph
  {
    //do whatever you want
  }
```

You can even define the table with id = 'table' and directly add data there from above selection.

eg:

```
 {
   var p=('#paragraph').fectchCode algo();
   $('#table').append(p);
 }
```

Comment: umm.jquery. i mean its not a working code.but he should get an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is the idea for the next step. However, I still need to split the plain text into paragraphs do I can reference it individually in my code.

Comment: yes.you can make text file to html.And you can give individual ID to each required paragraph.Say <p id='p1'>Your 1st text</p><p id ='p2'>your 2nd text</p>,then you can manipualte it by slecting with #p1,#p2 respectively.